# removeObjectForKey: Doesn't work in iPhone 5 simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios5, nsmutablearray

I'm a new developer, so this may be an obvious question.

When testing my code in the command-line tool I was able to use `removeObjectForKey:` to remove an `NSMutableArray` object I'd added to an `NSMutableDictionary`. When trying to build the same program for the iPhone 5 simulator it doesn't work.

### Does anyone know why?

edit:

here's some of my code that worked in the command line and won't work on the iPhone simulator. (my code displays random word lists.)

```
//adds NSMutableArrays to an NSDictionary called wordDictionary.
NSMutableDictionary *wordDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [wordDictionary setObject: list1 forKey:@"list1"];
        [wordDictionary setObject: list2 forKey:@"list2"];
        [wordDictionary setObject: list3 forKey:@"list3"];
...
//gets randomly selected array from dictionary to display
NSMutableArray *randomlySelectedArray = [wordDictionary objectForKey:randomKey];
...
//removes the randomly selected array from wordDictionery
[wordDictionary removeObjectForKey:randomKey];
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSMutableArray` doesn't respond to `-removeObjectForKey:`. That method belongs to `NSMutableDictionary`. Either you've written your question wrong, or you don't understand your code at all.

Comment: @interface NSMutableDictionary : NSDictionary

- (void)removeObjectForKey:(id)aKey;

Comment: thanks for the tip. thats from the docs so I'm a bit confused

Comment: Because in your question you said that you are removing it fron a **NSArray** (not a NSDictionary)

Comment: @OrpheusMercury: What makes you think it "won't work" in the simulator? You have yet to describe what your actual issue is.